# Trying to get around error: "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

> Enter integer: 99
>   Enter double: 3.77
>   Enter character: z
>   Enter string: Howdy
>   99 3.77 z Howdy

```
public class BasicInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInt = 99;
        double userDouble = 3.77;
        char userChar='z';
        String userString="Howdy";


        System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
        userInt = scnr.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter double : ");
        userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Character, ");
        userChar = scnr.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter String, ");
        userString = scnr.next();

        System.out.println(userInt+" "+userDouble+" "+userChar+" "+userString);

        System.out.println(userString+" "+userChar+" "+userDouble+" "+userInt);

        int castInt = (int) userDouble;

        System.out.println(""+userDouble+" cast to an integer is "+castInt);

        return;

    }
}
```

Trying to work around 
    Enter integer:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>         at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>         at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>         at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>         at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>         at BasicInput.main(BasicInput.java:13)

Comment: What did you enter? If not a number, then you get the exception. User error. Are you asking how to write input validation logic, so when user enters something wrong, the program will ask again? If so, edit the question and clarify: 1) What you did to get exception, 2) What you wanted to happen instead.

Comment: Tip: `hasNextInt`, `hasNextDouble`, and similar methods will let you catch an input error without an exception being throw.

Comment: Another tip: In `Scanner`, decimal separator is locale specific, so it can be a comma instead of point

Answer (score 0):

Read more about the exception you received:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.